# Can I skip or bypass translation when creating a form #options elements?

Tags: forms, i18n-l10n

I know I must use t() function in Drupal, but my particular task involves a great number of values in Russian, for which I do not want to enter values as
    t('Moscow')
and then manually translate strings into Russian. There are tons of Russian names and I just want to use them directly. Is it possible?

When I try, my select element options just appear blank.

```
...
       $form['selected'] = array(
           '#type' => 'select',
           '#title' => t('Selected'),
           '#options' => array(
              0 => 'Чебоксары',
              1 => 'Москва',
           ),
...
```

Comment: Should work all right. Are you sure your code files are properly saved as UTF-8 and transferred using "binary" mode? Also, how does HTML output of this field look like?

Comment: Thank you, it was stored as cp1251 in my editor. Changing to UTF-8 resolved the issue.

Comment: Posted it as an answer to remove your question from unanswered list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `t()` is considered a good practice, but it is in no way required by Form API.

Your code should work all right. Be sure your code files are properly saved as UTF-8 and transferred using "binary" mode, to prevent misinterpretation of non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks. This 'low quality filter' dance around is so stupid. Helpful answer though.